# Turn multiple bool values (from HTML form) into a string (Go)

Tags: go

I know the title is really bad, but not sure how to ask this question.. I have a HTML form with a select input returning multiple values, e.g.:

```
<select name="rights" multiple>
  <option value="create">create</option>
  <option value="view">view</option>
  <option value="edit">edit</option>
  <option value="delete">delete</option>
</select>
```

I then have a function that can check which values the form contains:

```
func formContains(slice []string, item string) bool {
    set := make(map[string]struct{}, len(slice))
    for _, s := range slice {
        set[s] = struct{}{}
    }
    _, ok := set[item]
    return ok
}
```

so I can call:

```
err := r.ParseForm()
// err check
rights := r.Form["rights"]
log.Println(formContains(rights, "create"))
```

What I would like to do is to check which values the form contains, and then return a string, e.g., if the form contains the rights "create" and "delete" then it should return:
"1001", if it contains the rights "view", "edit" and "delete" then it should return "0111".

I would be able to achieve the desired result with a lot of if/else or switch statements, but I know there must be a smarter way.. I considered the possibility of creating an array that would end up looking like this: [0] [1] [0] [1] (in case the rights were "view" and "delete"), and then convert the array to a string.. but so far it's been unsuccessful..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should look into the [bitwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) operations topic. There is no need to keep an array, your four operations can be represented as integers instead:

```
create = 1 (0001 in binary representation)
view   = 2 (0010 in binary representation)
edit   = 4 (0100 in binary representation)
delete = 8 (1000 in binary representation)
```

In order get all selected rights you can use `bitwise OR` operation:

```
rights := 0
rights |= 2
rights |= 4
// rights is 6 now, i.e. view and edit
```

Then when you need to check if specific right is enabled, you can use `bitwise AND` opration:

```
func hasPermission(rights int, item int) bool {
    return (rights & item) == item 
}
```

See my complete example: https://play.golang.org/p/UPZkqsrDS4

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


func main() {
    create := 1
    view   := 2
    edit   := 4
    delete := 8

    rights := 0
    rights |= view
    rights |= edit


    fmt.Println(hasPermission(rights , create))
    fmt.Println(hasPermission(rights , view))
    fmt.Println(hasPermission(rights , edit))
    fmt.Println(hasPermission(rights , delete))
}


func hasPermission(rights int, item int) bool {
    return (rights & item) == item 
}
```

Comment: Yep, bitwise logic FTW :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like

```
keys := []string{"create", "view", "edit", "delete"}
b := 0
for idx, key := range keys {
    if len(r.Form[key]) != 0 {
        b += 1 << uint(idx)
    }
}
fmt.Printf("%04b", b)
```

use `s := fmt.Sprintf("%04b", b)` to store the "binari rights string" into an string variable.

Comment: I think your answer did exactly what I asked, and I'd like to accept it, but I know I will end up using Pavel's method for my implementation, so can sadly just upvote it..